# Python: Setting attribute that is a lambda that just returns a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, cpython

While learning about decorator and decorator factories, I checked the source code of the `@functools.lru_cache` since it allows both usages using one single implementation. And I spotted something that is intriguing me. In the following statement `wrapper.cache_parameters = lambda : {'maxsize': maxsize, 'typed': typed}` extracted from this [piece of code from the CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2c28616ce6c3cdb1013c415125220a0b86b86a1/Lib/functools.py#L511):

```
def lru_cache(maxsize=128, typed=False):
    """<docstring ommited for brevity>"""
    if isinstance(maxsize, int):
        # Negative maxsize is treated as 0
        if maxsize < 0:
            maxsize = 0
    elif callable(maxsize) and isinstance(typed, bool):
        # The user_function was passed in directly via the maxsize argument
        user_function, maxsize = maxsize, 128
        wrapper = _lru_cache_wrapper(user_function, maxsize, typed, _CacheInfo)
        wrapper.cache_parameters = lambda : {'maxsize': maxsize, 'typed': typed}
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, user_function)
    elif maxsize is not None:
        raise TypeError(
            'Expected first argument to be an integer, a callable, or None')
    
    def decorating_function(user_function):
        wrapper = _lru_cache_wrapper(user_function, maxsize, typed, _CacheInfo)
        wrapper.cache_parameters = lambda : {'maxsize': maxsize, 'typed': typed}
        return update_wrapper(wrapper, user_function)
    
    return decorating_function
```

**What's the purpose of creating a lambda that only returns a dictionary instead of setting the dictionary directly to the attribute?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *After thinking a bit on the subject I came to this conclusion. But if there's another reason or you have a more complete explanation, please post an answer so I can accept it :)*

Dictionaries are mutable objects in Python. This means that anyone that has a reference to a dictionary can change it. So I think that the usage of the lambda here is a trick to make this a read-only attribute. Take a look at the following example:

```
def f():
    pass

f.a = lambda: {"a": 1}

ref = f.a()
ref
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': 1}
```

And if you change the returned dictionary, it will have no impact on the following calls to the lambda because a new dictionary is created in every call:

```
ref["b"] = 2
f.a()
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': 1}
```

As you can see in the example, **the returned dictionary is obviously still mutable**, but changing it has no effect in the returned value by the lambda itself.

In the [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/051ff526b5dc2c40c4a53d87089740358822edfa) that added this line, I also found the following note that supports my theory:

> The wrapped function is instrumented with a :func:`cache_parameters`
> function that returns a new :class:`dict` showing the values for *maxsize*
> and *typed*.  This is for information purposes only.  Mutating the values
> has no effect.

Comment: @RichardNeumann that's not what Hemerson said though.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I think you're mixing things. You are able to replace `wrapper.cache_parameters` with anything else because `wrapper` holds a mutable object. I never said that the dictionary becomes immutable. I said that the attribute provides access to read those values but it's impossible (I think) to change the specific dictionary that this specific lambda returns. I have added an example to try to clarify what I said.